# Performant Way to Check for Token Expiration in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently, for every call that comes to my ASP.NET Core MVC Application, I do the following in the `OnValidatePrincipal` event of the cookie:

1. Get the `id_token` out of the cookie via a call to `GetTokenValue`.
2. Call `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`'s ValidateToken to turn the token into json.
3. Get the `ValidTo` property out of the json.
4. Compare it to see if the token is expired.

It seems a bit excessive to me to do this on each an every call.  I am wondering if there is someway I can just store the ValidTo value in the cookie itself.  That way I would not have to parse out the json to check for expiration on each call.

**Is there a way I can get the `id_token`'s `ValidTo` stored such that a call like this could give me the expiration:  `GetTokenValue("id_token_valid_to")`?**

Comment: Do not store the ValidTo value in a cookie that defeats the purpose of using a JWT. You can only trust the information stored in the JWT. Did you measure how long it takes to check if the token is expired? I doubt it is anything to worry about. A secure system is much more valuable than having your server respond a few milliseconds faster

Comment: The web server is stateless, every request needs to be verified. The user cannot be trusted. "Why yes, I am an admin user, honest...."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

But in a couple of words you have to add something like this in your startup file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidAudience =Configuration["Tokens:Audience"] ,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            });
```

and after this you can check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in you base controler or authorization filter . If token is expired this is false. After this you can expirary date if you neeed.

Comment: I did not know that the `IsAuthenticated` would be false if the token was expired (though it makes sense that it would).  That will be a nice way to make it so that most calls do not need to check the expired date.  (Then when it is false, I can check to see if I need to use the update token.)  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, as you can see there is an option ValidateLifetime = true that checks a token lifetime. Pls dont forget to mark the answer is accepted  when it works for you.

Comment: @Serge Thanks a lot, in my opinion, this is the exact answer which I was looking for the last two weeks. I couldn't find any solution to handle the Lifetime Validation error.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea.

Do you think it is possible for you to set a Claim to the that is the same value of the JWT ExpiryDateTime. In the AttributeClass where you demand the token as a requirement you can have code that will read the Claims from the given Token, seek the claim pertaining to the DateTime Expiry and do a basic DateTime comparison against that?